# apache mesos is not recognized as a service in a ubuntu linux environment

Tags: mesos

Hi I am trying to install apache mesos in my ubuntu based system. I have installed zookeeper and marathon along with this setup.

```
apt-get install mesos marathon
```

it says its success but when i try to see available services systems does not show mesos-master or slaves as available services. also

```
service mesos-master/slave start
```

says unrecognized service. any idea?

Comment: when i have tried the same in linux mint, i could  see mesos and marathon as services but not zookeeper as a service. is there any reason why it is not consistent for different version of debian based linux?

Comment: Mesos does not have to use zookeeper, but zk is a very useful for larger clusters (see http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/high-availability/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so after trying multiple tricks .. I found that you can start the mesos-master using the following command:

```
mkdir ~/workdir; sudo mesos  master --work_dir=/home/azureuser/wokdir&
```

Comment: Thanks this tip solved my problem , I was completely confused

Answer (score 0):

Some [documentation](https://open.mesosphere.com/reference/packages/) has not matched actual installations for me - Mesos may installed to be managed by upstart/systemd kinds of commands rather than `service`. Most recently for me, a CentOS 6.6 install of Mesos has landed in `upstart`-managed territory, e.g.:

```
start mesos-master
stop mesos-master
status mesos-master
```

YMMV, but that's what I've recently seen.

Comment: can you please explain how i can check whether mesos goes into service list or upstart/systemd commands. I am new to linux installations. i have tried start/stop/status for mesos-master.  looks like its not making any diffence. I can see mesos-master, mesos-slave folders inside /etc/ folder. so i can assume installation is done correctly.

Comment: The presence of files in /etc/init (mesos-master.conf and/or mesos-slave.conf) has meant on my CentOS 6.x installs that upstart is in use, and the .conf files in 0.2x.y versions invoke /usr/bin/mesos-init-wrapper to to further config file loading and launching. Is anything related to mesos running? (Does "ps -e f | grep mesos" show anything?) Look also to /var/log for files/directories with mesos in their name - /varlog/mesos/mesos-{master,slave}.{INFO,WARNING,ERROR} kinds of patterns - if present, are there error messages present to provide clues?

Answer (score 0):

```
I faced same issue, I was not able to start mesos-master on UBUNTU-14.04 although I double checked installation and zookeeper service started successfully and tested well.

I found work around to start mesos-master service.
$ cd /usr/sbin/ 
$ sudo ./mesos-master --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --log_dir=/home/rajeev/logs/mesos/

above command run mesos-master service successfully [But sudo service mesos-master start  command failed to start mesos master node]
```